# Dependency loop despite entities configuration in Entity Framework. Include vs Join

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a question about Entity Framework. I use the Code First approach. Let's say I have several classes representing a table in a database. I use navigational properties and in some places the IDE highlights these properties and shows a warning that a dependency loop is possible. This warning appears even though these classes are configured with IEntityTypeConfiguration. In this case, should I give up navigational properties and use .Join, .GroupJoin in queries?